# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException при отправке сообщений из чужих сетей

Tags: java, android, smtp, gmail, javamail

Используем библиотеку [javamail-android](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) для отправки сообщений через SMTP-сервер Gmail в собственном приложении.

Все работает нормально, но только в тех сетях, в которых хотя бы раз выполнялся вход в соответствующий аккаунт Google.

Если приложение пытается отправить сообщение из чужой сети (напр. чужая точка доступа Wi-Fi) выпадает исключение `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`.

В настройках аккаунта  доступ к аккаунту для небезопасных приложений разрешен.

Проблема может быть решена предоставлением доступа к аккаунту Google: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha. Но такой вариант является небезопасным, т.к. данные доступа хранятся в приложении и могут быть использованы злоумышленниками.

Как решить данную проблему не теряя безопасности аккаунта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась включением [двухэтапной аутентификации](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) и использованием [пароля приложения](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) вместо пароля к аккаунту в нашем приложении.